# User access in concurrent

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I'm trying to find out about the problems of removing a module on an SMP system
Any good explanations?

Comment: what problems or modules are you looking at?

Answer (score 1):

The problems generally encountered is that there is some reference to the module in-flight somewhere on the system. This can be anything from a lock being held, some sort of callback in-flight - another module using a symbol, etc etc etc.

There are extensive reference counting systems inside the kernel which should be used to assist you in making sure this never occurs. Things that would use your module - or aspects of your module - would hold pertiant reference counts. The kernel will prevent your form doing an "rmmod" when this count is nonzero. You can see the reference count of all loaded modules in the "lsmod" outut.

Learn them and use them wisely.

These issues aren't really specific to "SMP" - but any kernel module. For example, if your module was a character driver, and someone opened your device, you wouldn't want your driver to unload while someone had a file descriptor opened on it - or worse yet - there was a process blocking on a read() awaiting a response. In many cases - like this - the kernel *itself* will hold references for you. In this case, a process opening a driver will hold a refcnt on the driver's module.